# .htaccess rewrite query string as path with multiple directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I m trying to do a very simple rewrite of a query string

```
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/test.php?id=8
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/test/8
```

and my code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*?)/?$ /test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

nut its not working i also try many solution provided on stackoverflow but nothing work please help me

Comment: _"not working"_ is insufficient.  Explain what is happening and what you have done to debug.

Comment: when i add this code its show url not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in `/directory1/directory2/`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory1/directory2/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ test/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/(\w+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: i have add the code but now css and js not loading when i use this code

Comment: my css files are http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/style.css now what should i do

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/directory1/directory2/" />`

Comment: yes its working fine can you please tell me if i want to remove the directroy from url means http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/test.php?id=8 to http://www.example.com//test/8 is it possible